# .htaccess Redirecting Too Many Times Using Get Variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect users from my main index page back to the index page but with a variable in the url to swap the loaded files. What I'm getting is too many redirects since I've added variables.

Here is what I've done:

```
 RewriteCond %{TIME} <20171201000000
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.000\.000\.000
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(styles|images|javascript).+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !construction.php$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|ttf|woff|js) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /construction [R=302,L]
```

This part works fine and redirects. However I've added a `case switch` function to my index page to eliminate the `construction.php` page altogether. So now I've made my redirect into this and it's redirecting too much.

```
 RewriteCond %{TIME} <20171201000000
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.000\.000\.000
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(styles|images|javascript).+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php?redirect=construction$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|ttf|woff|js) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /index.php?redirect=construction [R=302,L]
```

The reason I am doing this is because I am going to have several redirects from `construction` to `maintenance`, `404`, etc.

What would cause this to keep redirecting too much when all I did was change the urls?

Just for reference here is the entire `index.php` file:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/settings/config.php"; ?>
<body>
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/php/header.php"; ?>
<?php
    if (! isset($_GET['redirect']))
    {
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/index.main.php');

    } else {    
        $redirect = $_GET['redirect'];  
        switch($redirect)
        {
            case 'construction':
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/index.construction.php');
                break;  
            case 'maintenance':
                include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/index.maintenance.php');
                break;  
        }
    }
?>
<div class="container-fluid">
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/php/footer.php"; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php?redirect=construction$ [NC]
```

Because query string is not part of the test uri. Use instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=(?:construction|404)$ [NC]
```

You can omit the first line, If you use `redirect=construction` only for this page.

Comment: Works like a charm. `redirect=construction` is only used for the index page so no worries there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did run into one problem. I also added `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=404$ [NC]` to leave my `404` page open but it's still redirecting as well. This is how I am redirecting to my `404` `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?redirect=404`.

Comment: I add that now in my answer.

Comment: That puts it back into a redirect loop.